# Material UI Data Grid first column fixed

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Is it possible to make first column fixed when scrolling horizontally in Material Data Grid? I tried with selecting first child and applying `position: sticky` but it didn't work.
[image: Here is an example of my Data Grid]

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/193

Answer (score 2):

Column pinning is only available via the [MUI Pro Plan](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-pinning/), but it's as simple as adding the following line to an initialState prop in the DataGrid div.

```js
pinnedColumns: {left: ['actions']}
```

So, it will look like this:

```
<DataGrid 
    initialState={{
        pinnedColumns: { left: ['actions'] },
    }}
/>
```

"actions" of course being the `headerName/column` of whatever you want to pin and "left" the direction.

If you have more than one to pin, or want to pin multiple to different sides, simply add them after with commas between each.

```js
<DataGridPro
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  checkboxSelection
  initialState={{
    pinnedColumns: {
      left: [GRID_CHECKBOX_SELECTION_COL_DEF.field],
      right: ['actions', 'title', 'director', '...'],
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set pinned columns via initialState, pass an object with the following shape to this prop:

```html
interface GridPinnedColumns {
  left?: string[]; // Optional field names to pin to the left
  right?: string[]; // Optional field names to pin to the right
}
```

This feature is availabe in the Data Grid Pro only. more you can see here https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#column-pinning